# Haskell, rigid type error

Tags: haskell

Currently I am working on the following code segment

```
data Stream x = Stream [x]
              deriving Show


data Parser a b = P {
  runParser :: Stream a -> [(b, Stream a)]
}

whitespace :: Parser Char a -> Parser Char a
whitespace p = P p' where p' (Stream (x:xs)) | (x==' '||x=='\n'||x=='\t') = [(x, Stream xs)]
                         | otherwise = [(x, Stream xs)]
```

and I received an error like this

```
PComb.hs:72:16: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Char’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          whitespace :: forall a. Parser Char a -> Parser Char a
        at PComb.hs:71:1-44
      Expected type: Parser Char a
        Actual type: Parser Char Char
    • In the expression: P p'
      In an equation for ‘whitespace’:
          whitespace p
            = P p'
            where
                p' (Stream (x : xs))
                  | (x == ' ' || x == '\n' || x == '\t') = [(x, Stream xs)]
                  | otherwise = [(x, Stream xs)]
    • Relevant bindings include
        p :: Parser Char a (bound at PComb.hs:72:12)
        whitespace :: Parser Char a -> Parser Char a
          (bound at PComb.hs:72:1)
   |
72 | whitespace p = P p' where p' (Stream (x:xs)) | (x==' '||x=='\n'||x=='\t') = [(x, Stream xs)]
   |                ^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I was expecting that the `x` should be recognised as type `a` but how is that being recognised as a Char even I didn't really specify it is a `Char`? Appreciate for the help :)

Comment: You made the signature too generic, since `x` in `[(x, Stream xs)]` is the output of `p`, it means that the signature of `whitespace` is `Parser Char Char -> Parser Char Char`.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I was told not to change the signature, of course if I can change the signature, I would like to do that too.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the spec here. Notably, you're never using `p`. I think you need to go back to your assignment and figure out what it's actually asking you to do. That type implies a transformation of a parser in some manner, and the name of it isn't giving me any hint what it expects.

Answer (score 0):

`runParser` returns `[(b, Stream Char)]`, in the meantime the returned values you substitute are both `[(x, Stream xs)]` where `x` is of type `Char`. You should probably declare `whitespace` of type `Parser Char Char` instead of a free-variable type.

Comment: I also hope I can make the signature be more specific but I was told not to do so. Appreciated if there is an workout that can keep the signature ;)

Comment: But as the error message tells you, `x :: Char` is not a value for a free-variable type `forall a. a`.